# How can I add a menu entry that links to an external site?

Tags: plone

I would like to add a main tab to my plone site, that links to an external site in a new window.  I understand how to do this in a static html page, but I'm unsure how to do this the "Plone" way.  When I add a link content type to my home folder, the link just does a redirect in the current browser.

Ultimately, I'd like to have the link available in one of the main navigation tabs (along with my other main Plone tabs), but I'm not sure how to do that.  Is there any built-in functionality to handle this scenario?

I took a look at the code under Products.CMFPlone.skins.plone_content.link_redirect_view.py where I believe the link content type works.  It appears that the link is generated by doing this method:

```
return context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(context.getRemoteUrl())
```

How can I add a new type that does the same thing but just opens in a new window?

I'm currently running on CentOS 5.3 and Plone 4.1.2.

Comment: I found this article http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/How-do-I-make-external-links-open-in-new-window-in-Plone-3-td339743.html

Apparently it is a theme setting in the plone control panel, which isn't too intuitive.

Just wanted to give people the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This option can be found in the Types control panel page.

Just select the "Link" type and you should be presented with the option to "Redirect immediately to link target." I think that's what you're looking for.

The option in the Themes control panel page is more for links in content, not link objects.

Answer (score 2):

You could disable the auto generation of tabs and define your own tabs. Try this:

1. go to plone_control_panel -> Navigation Settings
2. disable "Automatically generate tabs"
3. go to plone_control_panel -> Zope Management Interface -> portal_actions -> portal_tabs.
4. using the menu in the top-right corner, add one "CMF Action" per menu entry that you need. You can use the "index_html" as example.

Action example:

*Title*: W3C

*URL (Expression)*: string:http://w3c.org

Note: disabling "Automatically generate tabs" is not mandatory, but if you leave it enabled then your custom actions will always appear before all auto generated tabs. It could be an option.

More info:

- http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/functionality/actions.html
- http://plone.org/products/plone-tabs/ (a useful product to easly customize your menu in the plone cp)

Comment: How can I get the newly created link to open a new window?  I cannot find a way to customize the html of the link to open in a new window.  This is what I was mainly going for.  Without these steps and this product, I could be able create an external link.  I would like the functionality where the link will open a new browser window.  Any ideas on that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this article http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/How-do-I-make-external-links-open-in-new-window-in-Plone-3-td339743.html

Apparently it is a theme setting in the plone control panel, which isn't too intuitive.

Just wanted to give people the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `portal_actions` in the ZMI to create a new navigation tab. In the URL expression field enter the site URL. i.e. `'string:http://www.thesite.com'`. The new tab will appear on your top navigation, and will link straight to the site you specify.

For more info have a look here - http://plone.org/documentation/kb/changing-tabs